# Organizing .po localization files for Django

Tags: python, django, localization, po, django-multilingual

The project I am working on has gotten pretty big. As have it's localization files. It has gotten hard to find your way around the translations.

How do you manage big localization files in your django projects? I would like to separate the *.po files by context. (e.g. email, push message, web view etc.)

That way I could add them to different translation projects at **poeditor** or **onesky** etc.

Answer (score 1):

Intersting question. At the moment Django hardcodes the gettext *domain* to `django`, so you cannot rely on this namespacing capability. There is an [open and active issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6376) about this.

You may want to use [alternate `LOCALE_PATHS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) though.

Comment: Would that help though? I would still have to write a script to split and merge the django.po files.

Comment: Do you mean that `makemessages` would still create a single big file? I guess so. This is not a trivial task. You may use `--ignore` to selectively create the `po` files for each source directory. This is quite hacky though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Contextual Markers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers).

They will add `msgctxt` to your `.po` files. You can then easily create a script which leaves only `msgctxt "email"` in the `.po` file, translate this subset and then merge the results for compilation.

Comment: I guess writing your own script is the only solution. Good thing I have those contextual markers already in place.